# Content Type inherited from Folder not showing custom fields in Forms

Tags: content-type, list-form

I created via xml declaration a content type which is based on the folder content type. I set `"inherits=FALSE"` due to the declaratively adding of event receivers to the content type.
My Problem now is that the content type is not showing the custom fields which I added as well to the content type the only thing which is showing up is for example the standard NewForm for Folders:

[image]

Has anyone an idea why the content type is behaving like this?
In PowerShell I can manipulate the fields of an created Item as I which but the forms are not showing these fields.
Even if I add some additional fields to the list content type there is no change to the forms at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Folder (0x0120) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x012000XXX" Name="Work Package" Group="CTS" Description="Work Package Content Type based on Folder" 
        Inherits="FALSE" Version="0" Hidden="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE">
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
        <Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
          <Receiver>
            <Name>ItemAdded</Name>
            <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
            <Class>$SharePoint.Type.xxx.FullName$</Class>
            <Data></Data>
            <Filter></Filter>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>ItemDeleting</Name>
            <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
            <Class>$SharePoint.Type.xxx.FullName$</Class>
            <Data></Data>
            <Filter></Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>ItemUpdating</Name>
            <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
            <Class>$SharePoint.Type.xxx.FullName$</Class>
            <Data></Data>
            <Filter></Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>ItemUpdated</Name>
            <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
            <Class>$SharePoint.Type.xxx.FullName$</Class>
            <Data></Data>
            <Filter></Filter>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
          </Receiver>
        </Receivers>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{xxx}" DisplayName="Work Package" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" Name="Title" />
      <FieldRef ID="{xxx}" DisplayName="Work Package ID" Required="TRUE" Name="WorkPackageID" />
      <FieldRef ID="{xxx}" DisplayName="Work Package Title" Required="FALSE" Name="WorkPackageTitle" />
      <FieldRef ID="{xxx}" DisplayName="Lead" Required="TRUE" Name="Lead" />
      <FieldRef ID="{xxx}" DisplayName="Part" Required="FALSE" Name="Part" />     
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

**UPDATE:**
The issue is only occurring in Document Libraries, if I add this content type to a custom list, all fields are showing up correctly.
In addition to that SharePoint is totally ignoring the required property at the content type. Therefore it seems that it is not processing the at all.

Comment: You added custom fields to the Parent Folder content type or the one you want to use?

Comment: No I created a new Content Type based on the Folder Content Type and used this in lists.

Comment: And these custom fields you added into the new content type right?

Comment: what happens if you add the attribute ShowInNewForm = true and ShowInEditForm = true?

Comment: So in you list/library you must be having more than 1 content type now. You need to make sure you select correct content type from the new button on ribbon control. As the default CT is ITEM and it has only Title column.

Comment: Changing the attribute `ShowInNewForm="TRUE"` and `ShowInEditForm="TRUE"` did not make any changes. 
And yes I know the behavior of having multiple content types on a list/library.

Comment: Are you using CT Hub by any chance?

Comment: No the Content Type hub is not being used at all. I don't have any clue right now what in detail is wrong, because the content type works correctly if it is attached to a list. If it is attached to a document library it is not working. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who have the same problem. I guess I found the solution.
In the declaration there is the definition of the Forms missing. If you add it as a xml document to the elements.xml

```
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
<FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
    <Display>ListForm</Display>
    <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
    <New>ListForm</New>
  </FormTemplates>
</XmlDocument>
```

It works fine.